# sending message on invalid destination in xa transaction

Tags: java, transactions, jms, xa

When you use send method of MessageProducer in while xa transaction in progress to send message on destination which is not available on JMS provider in this case send method doesn't throw any exception instead it throws exception while commiting transaction. If send method is not part of xa transaction it throws InvalidDestinationException. why it don't throw exception when its is part of xa transaction ?? I am using arjuna tm for transactions.

Comment: Which JMS implementation are you using? Send will behave very differently when used in a transcation and out of a transaction. You cannot really compare when various exceptions will be thrown. Is this a problem for you? The transaction should be atomic no matter where the exception occurs.

Comment: Yes, There is no problem in transaction it's perfectly atomic but why it behaves differently. 
How can i know destination is invalid if there's no Invalid destination error
This behavior is JBOSS JTA specific or all TM behaves like this ??
Does TM override behavior of Application??

Comment: Its not the JTA implementation that is doing the destination name lookup (or not). It's the JMS implementation that decides where such things should be done. For instance, ActiveMQ usually doesn't care if a destination exists - but creates one on the fly in this scenario. You have to look into how your JMS implementation does these things and if it's even configurable.